# Erasing only a part of an excel with win32com and python

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, win32com

I have 3 parameters.

startLine, starColumn and width (here 2,8,3)

[image: excel]

How can I erase the selected area without writing blanks in each cells?
(here there is only 30 line but there could potetialy be 10 000 lines)

Right now I'm succesfully counting the number of lines but I can't manage to find how to select and delete an area

```
self.startLine = 2
self.startColumn = 8
self.width = 8

self.xl = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
self.xl.Visible = 1
self.xl.ScreenUpdating = False
self.worksheet = self.xl.Workbooks.Open("c:\test.xls")
sheet = self.xl.Sheets("data")

#Count the number of line of the record
nb = 0
while sheet.Cells(start_line + nb, self.startColumn).Value is not None:
    nb += 1

#must select from StartLine,startColumn to startcolum+width,nb
#and then erase

self.worksheet.Save()
```

ps : the code works, I may have forgotten some part due do copy/pas error, in reality the handling of the excel file is managed by several classes inheriting from each other

thanks

Comment: Can you see the image? it's being blocked on my network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do is that I record macro in Excel and than try to re-hack the VB in Python. For deleting content I got something like this, should not be hard to convert it to Python:

```
Range("H5:J26").Select
Selection.ClearContents
```

In Python it should be something like:

```
self.xl.Range("H5:J26").Select()
self.xl.Selection.ClearContents()
```

Working example:

```
from win32com.client.gencache import EnsureDispatch

exc = EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
exc.Visible = 1
exc.Workbooks.Open(r"f:\Python\Examples\test.xls")
exc.Sheets("data").Select()
exc.Range("H5:J26").Select()
exc.Selection.ClearContents()
```

Comment: except range cannot be applied to any of my object (self.xl or self.worksheet or sheet)

Comment: OK, let me try then for real :-).

Comment: thank you, thank you :D
But why opening with EnsureDispatch gives me more methods?

Comment: That is actually a great question ... for someone else :-). I have no idea, that is the way I have learned some time ago and I have never known there is a difference like this.

Comment: bothering you again, is there a way to use numbers insted of Ax Bx Cx, etc when selecting?

Comment: I do not think so, but that should not be a problem, converting number to letter and using string formatting to put it in there. Something along this line: `chr(ord("A") + column - 1)`. However this works only for first 26 columns. More would require a bit more elaborate conversion.

Comment: And I finnaly found the difference betwen EnsureDispatch and Dispatch http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/generate-a-static-com-proxy.html

Comment: @sliders_alpha - Nice! I always find it, learn it and immediately forget it until next problem with COM objects :-).

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
xl = EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application') 
wb2=xl.Workbooks.Open(file)
ws=wb2.Worksheets("data")

ws.Range("A12:B20").ClearContents()
```